# Check if var contains CSSStyleRule (get object name)

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a variable contains a CSSStyleRule. When using `window.console.log(myvar)` it tells me `CSSStyleRule { constructor=CSSStyleRule, type=1, more...}`, but when I use `typeof myvar` it just tells me `object`.

How can I check if it is really a CSSStyleRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if the object has the `selectorText` property:

```
if(myvar.selectorText) {

    ... 

}
```

Comment: @Zardoz Note that a `CSSRule` object also contains a `selectorText` propertiy, and so does this object `{selectorText:0}`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
myvar instanceof CSSStyleRule
```

This expression returns true/false.